# How can I find the max value from an array of arrays?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I need to find the max value from an array, whose elements are an array, which consists of two elements, first of which is a string representing time and the second an integer. I want the maximum and the minimum values among the second elements of the arrays.

```
a = [
  ["2015-04-01 20:51:03 +0530", 7],
  ["2015-04-01 20:51:03 +0530", 11],
  ["2015-04-01 20:51:03 +0530", 8],
  ["2015-04-01 20:51:03 +0530", 8],
  ["2015-04-01 20:51:03 +0530", 8],
  ["2015-04-01 20:51:03 +0530", 8],
  ["2015-04-01 20:51:05 +0530", 8],
  ["2015-04-01 20:51:05 +0530", 20],
  ["2015-04-01 20:51:05 +0530", 0],
  ["2015-04-01 20:51:05 +0530", 2],
  ["2015-04-01 20:51:05 +0530", 1],
  ["2015-04-01 20:51:05 +0530", 9]
]
```

Any idea what the best way is to do this?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would use `map` to collect the elements from the nested arrays. Once that it done, just use `min`, `max` or `minmax` on that collection.

```
a = [["2015-04-01 20:51:03 +0530", 7], ["2015-04-01 20:51:03 +0530", 11], ["2015-04-01 20:51:03 +0530", 8], ["2015-04-01 20:51:03 +0530", 8], ["2015-04-01 20:51:03 +0530", 8], ["2015-04-01 20:51:03 +0530", 8],["2015-04-01 20:51:05 +0530", 8], ["2015-04-01 20:51:05 +0530", 20], ["2015-04-01 20:51:05 +0530", 0], ["2015-04-01 20:51:05 +0530", 2], ["2015-04-01 20:51:05 +0530", 1], ["2015-04-01 20:51:05 +0530", 9]]

values = a.map(&:last)

values.min
#=> 0

values.max
#=> 20

values.minmax
#=> [0, 20]
```

Answer (score 5):

Some other ways :

```
a.max_by(&:last)
# => ["2015-04-01 20:51:05 +0530", 20]
a.max_by(&:last).last # => 20
a.min_by(&:last).last # => 0
```